# Margin bottom not pushing div upwards

Tags: html, css, margin

I have an div top-bar with padding and inside that I have a div logo. I gave the div logo an margin-bottom but it is not pushing the logo upwards.
When I look at the source I can see that the margin is overlapping the top-bar.
Someone can take an look what is wrong?

```css
#top-bar {
  background-color: black;
  padding: 1%;
  width: auto;
  height: 50px;
  display: block;
}

#left-menu {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 5%;
  height: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 5%;
}

#navigation {
  /* width: 100%; */
  float: right;
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 5%;
  height: 50px; 
}
```

```html
<doctype html>
  <head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title> Dif Connect </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
  </head>
<html lang="en">
  <body>
    <div id="top-bar">
      <div id="left-menu">
        <img src="icons/diflogo.png" width="70px" height="70px" />
      </div>
      <div id="navigation">
        <ul>
          <li><img src="icons/instagram.png"/>  <a class="link" href="#"></a></li>
          <li><img src="icons/twitter.png"/>   <a class="link" href="#"></a></li>
          <li><img src="icons/facebook.png"/> <a class="link" href="#"></a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Scripts attached to this html -->
    <script>  src="script.js"</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is a result of the explicit `height` values declared on the elements in question - removing these heights will demonstrate this. Consider using `top` and `bottom` positioning properties to offset an element's position when the element has no *room* to move within the constrained proportions of its containing parent element. Note that before declaring any `left`, `right`, `top` or `bottom` properties, the element must be *positioned* (not `position: static`)

Answer (score 0):

```css
#top-bar {
  background-color: black;
  padding: 1%;
  width: auto;
  height: 50px;
  display: block;
}

#left-menu {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 5%;
  height: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 5%;
}

#navigation {
  /* width: 100%; */
  float: right;
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 5%;
  height: 50px; 
}
```

```html
<doctype html>
  <head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title> Dif Connect </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
  </head>
<html lang="en">
  <body>
    <div id="top-bar">
      <div id="left-menu">
        <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/87452/flowers-background-butterflies-beautiful-87452.jpeg?h=350&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb 1x, https://images.pexels.com/photos/87452/flowers-background-butterflies-beautiful-87452.jpeg?h=350&dpr=2&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb 2x" width="70px" height="55px" />
      </div>
      <div id="navigation">
        <ul>
          <li><img src="icons/instagram.png"/>  <a class="link" href="#"></a></li>
          <li><img src="icons/twitter.png"/>   <a class="link" href="#"></a></li>
          <li><img src="icons/facebook.png"/> <a class="link" href="#"></a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Scripts attached to this html -->
    <script>  src="script.js"</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If any issues let me know.

Comment: My logo is so small now and the fonts on the logo are bad readable now, that's the reason I made it bigger but then it will overlap the top-bar, any suggestion's.

Comment: Can you check my above code by running.If other issues please send me screen shot with mark.

Comment: https://prnt.sc/hhopzt 
Please mark in above screen shot where you are getting issues.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/caVFP how can I make the margin push to picture upwards? with the 100px logo.

Answer (score 0):

```
    #top-bar {
  background-color: black;
  padding: 1%;
  width: auto;
  height: 60px;
}

#left-menu {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 5%;
  height: 50px;

}

#navigation {
  /* width: 100%; */
  color: #fff;
  float: right;
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 5%;
  height: 50px; 
}

 <body>
    <div id="top-bar">
      <div id="left-menu">
        <img src="icons/diflogo.png" width="60px" height="60px" />
      </div>
      <div id="navigation">
        <ul>
          <li><img src="icons/instagram.png"/>  <a class="link" href="#"></a></li>
          <li><img src="icons/twitter.png"/>   <a class="link" href="#"></a></li>
          <li><img src="icons/facebook.png"/> <a class="link" href="#"></a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>`
  </body>
```